# invert pose parameter in "Fitting A Model To New Points" "Active Shape Model"

Tags: c++

I don't understand what is "invert pose parameter" to do this [T Transformation](http://min.us/lbfdrFI5iD8Hl9)?

pose parameter are: Xt, Yt, delta, s in above formula:

[formula](http://min.us/l1b83zPMBC4Qq)

Comment: How is it related to C++?

Comment: Because I use C++ to do this method.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, It seem be like no one answer my question. But finally, I found it by myself.

invert pose parameter of T(X), that mean find the pose parameters to X = T^-1(T(X)). Here we go, invert pose parameter must be:

Xt = -Xt;

Yt = -Yt;

s = 1/s;

theta = -theta;